# When running Docker on Raspberry Pi starting containers fails from time to time

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian

I have installed Docker (0.8.0-1) by running the steps [described in the Resin.io blog](http://resin.io/blog/docker-on-raspberry-pi-in-4-simple-steps/). Basically, everything works well and I am able to start the Docker daemon as well as run the client.

Unfortunately, when I try to run a container it *sometimes* fails. This does not depend on the actual container, as when you repeat the command it works. Sometimes it needs more than two trials, and sometimes it also works on the first try. My `run` command basically looks like:

```
$ docker run -i -t --rm=true resin/rpi-raspbian bash
```

So, nothing fancy so far… the error message I get only tells me that the container exited with `code 1`, whatever this means.

Basically, the same happens when I try to `build` a Dockerfile: Usually it works for a single step and fails on the next one. As Docker internally caches the results, you can build a Dockerfile by executing it again and again manually, and on every run you get one step further. If it fails, again `code 1`.

The exact error message is:

> 2014/02/27 18:15:45 Error: start: Cannot start container 99fc6a3327fb4af25e6c7a07d992009dde8a5425de89f44aae76ce4740e09492: exit status 1

It surprises me that when I run a `docker ps -a` afterwards, the containers did not get removed (at least, the ones that could not be created are still there) - and, what's even more surprising, this command lists the status code as `-1`.

I don't see anything in the logs, when I run

```
$ docker logs 99fc
```

What might cause these issues?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, there is neither a `/var/log/messages` folder nor a `/var/log/syslog` folder on the system, but if I run `dmesg` the last lines are:

```
[56954.479079] device veth4FI4FH entered promiscuous mode
[56955.270388] docker0: port 1(veth4FI4FH) entered forwarding state
[56955.270493] docker0: port 1(veth4FI4FH) entered forwarding state
[56955.480603] docker0: port 1(veth4FI4FH) entered disabled state
[56955.484685] device veth4FI4FH left promiscuous mode
[56955.484726] docker0: port 1(veth4FI4FH) entered disabled state
```

**UPDATE 2**

I now found out that I get extended logs by calling `journalctl` (as I am on a systemd-based system). I get:

```
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: 2014/02/28 09:31:02 POST /v1.9/containers/create
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job create()
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job create() = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: 2014/02/28 09:31:02 POST /v1.9/containers/8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job inspect(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916, container)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job inspect(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916, container) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job attach(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: 2014/02/28 09:31:02 POST /v1.9/containers/8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916/start
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job start(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job allocate_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job allocate_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job allocate_port(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:02 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job allocate_port(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:03 white docker[123]: [error] container.go:1244 Error running container: exit status 1
Feb 28 09:31:03 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job release_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:03 white kernel: device vethHXP55Y entered promiscuous mode
Feb 28 09:31:03 white avahi-daemon[131]: Withdrawing workstation service for vethUTI4YT.
Feb 28 09:31:03 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job release_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:03 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job attach(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] +job release_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916)
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: 2014/02/28 09:31:04 Unable to unmap port 0.0.0.0:80: port is not mapped
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: [/docker|5cd5747f] -job release_interface(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = OK (0)
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: [error] container.go:1299 8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916: Error closing Pty master: invalid argument
Feb 28 09:31:04 white kernel: docker0: port 1(vethHXP55Y) entered forwarding state
Feb 28 09:31:04 white kernel: docker0: port 1(vethHXP55Y) entered forwarding state
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: Cannot start container 8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916: exit status 1[/docker|5cd5747f] -job start(8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916) = ERR (1)
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: [error] api.go:959 Error: start: Cannot start container 8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916: exit status 1
Feb 28 09:31:04 white docker[123]: [error] api.go:91 HTTP Error: statusCode=500 start: Cannot start container 8d2928a6a4b4c57aa2760a3681a5fbcf53f890e85d6830b97b9245366d284916: exit status 1
Feb 28 09:31:04 white kernel: docker0: port 1(vethHXP55Y) entered disabled state
Feb 28 09:31:04 white avahi-daemon[131]: Withdrawing workstation service for vethHXP55Y.
Feb 28 09:31:04 white kernel: device vethHXP55Y left promiscuous mode
Feb 28 09:31:04 white kernel: docker0: port 1(vethHXP55Y) entered disabled state
```

So apparently the problem is in `container.go:1244` while trying to start the container.

Is this of any help?

Comment: Docker is implemented with cgroups (lxc) in the linux kernel. When they go wrong any information will be written to the console, dmesg or /var/log/syslog (sometimes called /var/log/messages on some distributions)

Comment: Just checked. Output on the console is what I've written in the question. Unfortunately, neither /var/log/syslog nor /var/log/messages do exist, but there is a /var/log/lxc folder with logs for each container: Unfortunately, the file `99c….log` is empty :-(. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you used our Resin port of Docker I'll assume that you're running Arch Linux. In Arch Linux the latest LXC package is lxc-1.0 and Docker has known problems with this version of LXC [1].

Downgrading LXC to 0.9 or 0.8 should fix the problem. Arch Linux keeps a cache of packages recently downloaded in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`. So, as root, do `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/lxc-<VERSION>` and then restart your Docker daemon.

If you don't find a cached package there you'll find more ways to do it here [2].

[1] *[Race condition with lxc-info #4298](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4298)* (GitHub)

[2] *[Downgrading packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages)* (Arch Linux wiki)

Comment: Yes, we are using ArchLinux (and quite a new version). We'll give it a try next week and let you know the results. Anyway, thanks so much already for your help :-)))

Comment: We tried to follow your instructions. As we couldn’t locate any old versions of lxc in our local pacman cache we tried to scan the internet and the Arch Rollback Machine for old versions of lxc and found them here http://seblu.net/a/arm/packages/l/lxc/. But unfortunately the archives only contain packages that were compiled for other architectures (x86, i686) and since we’re running on a Pi we need a package compiled for armv6. Do know about any download mirrors for old armv6 packages? Thanks in advance for any tip or hint into the right direction :-)!

Comment: In that case I'd recommend just git cloning the PKGBUILD files and manually compiling the specific version of lxc that you want. This is the repo that you should clone 

https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/

And you need to checkout commit 5b9771f90ab03550396835ffc1c47dd619553ff5